gmodels::fit.contrast equivalent in Python
I would like to test for synergy between 2 drugs given to animals, and I measured the tumor growth at different time-points in 15 animals in each group.
I use the statistical test for Bliss independence synergy, which is a modified t-statistic derived from the principles of linear models and the properties of the t-distribution. This statistic essentially measures the difference between the combined effect and the sum of individual effects, as nicely described elsewhere.
The code in R uses a straightforward approach with a contrast matrix:
model.fit <- lm(lnTV ~ lnTV.baseline + Group, data = TV.data.day)
fit.combo <- gmodels::fit.contrast(model.fit, "Group", c(1, -1, -1, 1), conf.int = 0.9, df = TRUE)

Is there a way to leverage the contrast matrix in Python, for example using statsmodels.stats.contrast of anything with patsy.constrasts? I couldn't translate the methods described in the documents Contrast Overview or the Contrast coding system.

As an alternative you can reuse the same code from R package by calling it from Python:
Create an R function that will call fit.contrast
# code.R
library("gmodels")

myfunction= function(dataset){
    dataset$Group <- as.factor(dataset$Group)
    model.fit <- lm(lnTV ~ baseline + Group, data = dataset)
    fit.combo <- gmodels::fit.contrast(model.fit, "Group", c(1, -1, -1, 1), conf.int = 0.9, df = TRUE)
    fit.combo
}

Then call it from python:
# script.py
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


r = robjects.r
r['source']('code.R') # preload code from the R file


# sample dataset, replace with any other data
data = pd.DataFrame({"lnTV": np.random.random(size=20),
                     "baseline": np.random.random(size=20),
                     "Group":np.random.randint(1,5, size=20)
              })

with (robjects.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter).context():
    # Loading the function we have defined in R.
    myfunction_r = robjects.globalenv['myfunction']
    dd = myfunction_r(data) # this will call your R funciton
    
    # output derived from the R function
    print(dd) 

